# ActiveMQ MQTT (QoS 1) doesn't republish messages when client not acknowledged the messages

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.10 as the MQTT Broker with one Java client to send messages in JMS and one C client to receive the messages.

Here's the Java code snippet:

```
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(new ActiveMQTopic("topic1"));
TextMessage text = session.createTextMessage("test msg");
text.setIntProperty("ActiveMQ.MQTT.QoS",1);
producer.send(text);
```

After capturing the TCP packages, I confirmed the problem: If ActiveMQ sent out a message but didn't receive a PUBACK from the C client, ActiveMQ didn't resend the message. So the C client would never receive the message any more, event the message was under QoS 1 (at-least-once).

How can I send the message with JMS (and/or configure ActiveMQ) to make QoS 1 truely work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's a very old version lacking many MQTT fixes, you need to move to the latest release to get things fixed.

Comment: Thank you, Tim! I'm trying to upgrade it

Comment: ActiveMQ 5.14 doesn't republish the message either. Should the message be persistent?

Comment: OMG, MQTT v3.1.1 doesn't require to resend the message ([MQTT v3.1.1 Section 4.4](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/errata01/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc442180916)): `When a Client reconnects with CleanSession set to 0, both the Client and Server MUST re-send any unacknowledged PUBLISH Packets (where QoS > 0) and PUBREL Packets using their original Packet Identifiers [MQTT-4.4.0-1]. This is the only circumstance where a Client or Server is REQUIRED to redeliver messages.`